# PHP Date to strtotime and back to date?

Tags: php, timezone, strtotime

What I want to do is to convert a time string with strtotime and then back to date with the timezone that it had before.

I am using the following code, but the time I get as a result is in UTC:

```
$timeStart = "2013-04-25 18:14:00+03";
$datetimeStart = strtotime($timeStart);
$datetimeNext = strtotime('+8 hours',$datetimeStart);
$time = gmdate('Y-m-d\\TH:i:s\\Z', $datetimeNext);
```

Any ideas? Thank you..

Comment: The time you get as a result from which variable?

Comment: the last one... $time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that you want the same *offset* as you originally had.  Read "TimeZone != Offset" in [the TimeZone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

The main problem with your request is that `strtotime` (according to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)) returns an integer representing number of seconds from the epoch *in UTC*.  So any offset you provide is going to be factored in but then forgotten about.

Sorry I don't know PHP well enough to provide a code sample, but you can probably extract the offset from the original string and then re-apply it at the end.  It is also possible there is a different way to parse the string that will yield an object that maintains the offset.  Again, I don't know PHP well enough to help you here.  In .Net the same problem would be solved by parsing into a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`.

Also - logistically the offset you start with is not necessarily the correct offset to use after you add time.  You might have crossed a daylight savings time transition, which would make the new correct offset an hour less or an hour more than the original offset.  You may or may not care about this, depending on your concerns.  The only way to get to correct offset after an edit is to also know what time zone the original value was in.

Comment: thanks..that helped me a lot.. I hadn't thought about the daylight savings time transition!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `date` instead of `gmdate`

```
$time = date('Y-m-d\\TH:i:s\\Z', $datetimeNext);
```

Comment: the result is 2013-04-25T23:14:00Z, still UTC??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use putenv to set your timezone prior to making the strtotime conversion.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

```
putenv("TZ=US/Central");
$today = date('F j, Y, g:i a');
$newdate = strtotime ($today) ;
$newdate = date ( 'F j, Y' , $newdate );
```

Comment: the thing is I don't know the timezone.. It depends on what timezone $timeStart has.. i got $ timestart from a db and timezone might be different each time..